# C# - static method or create new Instance when using third party library

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a class that only implement a third party library - And I can tell you that is [Google Cloud](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-dotnet).

I'm wondering while using this kind of libraries, how to use it properly?

Here are my examples show how I use:

**New Instance**

Declaration

```
public class MyClass{
        private readonly string _jsonPath= ...;

        public readonly StorageClient Client;

        public MyClass()
        {
            var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(_jsonPath);
            Client = StorageClient.Create(credential);
        }

        public string Upload(/*my parameter*/)
        {
            Client.UploadObject(...);
            // etc
        }
}
```

---

Usage

```
var myInstance = new MyClass();

myInstance.Upload(...);
```

**Static Method**

Declaration

```
public class MyClass{
        private static readonly string _jsonPath= ...;

        public static readonly StorageClient Client = StorageClient.Create(GoogleCredential.FromFile(_jsonPath));

        public static string Upload(/*my parameter*/)
        {
            Client.UploadObject(...);
            // etc
        }
}
```

---

Usage

```
MyClass.Upload(...);
```

---

Since the methods will be called concurrently very frequently, I would like to know what kind of usage is better and why to avoid problems.

As far as I know, static is not good at sharing the same class members,

but I think to declare the client every time I need to use is redundant.

I would like to know more about this two way's pros and cons.

Any advice will be appreciated.

My English is pretty basic, please don't mind.

**Thanks for your reading.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your MyClass requirements, this is a bit tough to answer. What does MyClass do? Does it require some setup? Building? Does the Upload method depend on instance state?

I generally like to inject my external dependencies, and hide them behind interfaces. That way I create test doubles, and easilly change the dependencies if I want to. I tend to not like using statics unless it is for stateless utility classes, like Maths, string manipulation, extensions and other stateless processing.

For things that require state, I use instances. If I really need shared state, I use a singleton, but I try to avoid them if possible.

In your case I would create a IStorageProvider, implement a GoogleCloudStorageProvider, and put a dependency of IStorageProvider on MyClass.

```
public class MyClass {
    IStorageProvider Storage;
    public MyClass(IStorageProvider storage)
    {
        Storage = storage;
    }
    public async void Upload(Data data){
        await Storage.Save(data);
    }
}

public interface IStorageProvider{
    void Upload(Data data);
}

public class GoogleCloudStorage:IStorageProvider{
    private Credentials Creds;
    private GoogleCloudClient Client;
    public GoogleCloudStorage(Credentials creds)
    {
        Creds = creds;
        Client = new GoogleCloudClient();
    }

    private void Connect(){
        Client.Connect(Creds);
    }
    public async void Upload(Data data){
        if(!Client.Connected){
            Connect();
        }
        return await Client.Upload(data);
    }
}
```

I feel that this approach is a bit more flexible.

Comment: Got it! MyClass do only collect and transform data that will be needed by google functions. I have created several class for several google service. So I think it's more like static method but I don't know using  google sdk instance as static is proper.

Answer (score 2):

You can use static class for often use component.but I recommend you should use singleton design pattern for this process.

Comment: I don't know what's the difference between singleton and static method here.

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/difference-between-singleton-class-and-static-class1    https://medium.com/@hakantopuz/singleton-design-pattern-nedir-nas%C4%B1l-%C3%A7al%C4%B1%C5%9F%C4%B1r-nas%C4%B1l-kullan%C4%B1l%C4%B1r-be655b13978c

Comment: oh, I know the difference of both. I mean it looks like no difference between them in my usage. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with your first approach and change your Upload method to be asynchronous so that independent tasks can run concurrently. With your second approach you could have two different threads which are altering the same object in a non thread-safe way.

Do something like this:

```
public class MyClass{

    private readonly string _jsonPath= ...;
    private readonly StorageClient _storageClient;

    public MyClass()
    {
        var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(_jsonPath);
        _storageClient = StorageClient.Create(credential);
    }

    public Task<string> UploadAsync(/*my parameter*/)
    {
        var imageObject = await _storageClient.UploadObjectAsync(...);
        // etc
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a good idea. But I would like to know what if the third party library doesn't implement an asynchronous method? Could I use it by single instance safely?

Comment: @TerryWei You are using ASP.NET MVC which means that the framework will always instantiate a new controller instance for each http request. So it's not thread-safe to call methods from your "MyClass". However, if your library doesn't provide asynchronous methods, you just can wrap those calls in Tasks.